# MSCRM 4 Convert Standard entity to Custom entity using InitializeFromRequest

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to convert an order and orderdetail lines to a custom entity and its child lines using InitializeFromRequest using the code below:

```
public void Convert(Guid FromEntityId, string FromEntityName, string ToEntityName)
{
    try
    {
        // Set up the CRM Service.
        CrmService _service = GetCrmService();

        InitializeFromRequest req = new InitializeFromRequest();
        req.EntityMoniker = new Moniker(); // this is the very thing that does the job.

        req.EntityMoniker.Id = FromEntityId;
        req.EntityMoniker.Name = FromEntityName;
        req.TargetEntityName = ToEntityName;  //contact for our example req.

        req.TargetFieldType = TargetFieldType.ValidForCreate;
        InitializeFromResponse rps = (InitializeFromResponse)_service.Execute(req);
        //now the lead is converted to a contact, and you can see it in contacts.
        Guid entityId = _service.Create(rps.Entity);
        lblMsg.Text = "Done ID:" + entityId.ToString();
    }            
    catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException se)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "soap:" + se.Detail.InnerText;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Now I am able to get a custom entity created but all the attributes are empty despite me setting the mapping fields in the realtionship.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ReturnDynamicEntities = true when converting an standard entity to a custom one.